# iOS Distribution signing - Crash on startup on non-debug builds

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, crash, signing

I'm having a very weird problem happening with my iOS signing with which I've been struggling for a while.

It goes like this:

- sign an app with a development certificate/profile, and run it on a device, it works perfectly.
- sign an app with a distribution certificate/ad-hoc profile, and run it on a device, it goes in a gray screen for 20s then crashes.
- run the app signed with development credentials, then run the one signed with distribution credentials on top of it (install without uninstalling previous version), it works perfectly.

I cannot get through this in any way shape or form I'd try. Different developer accounts, different app ids, different distribution certificate and different provisioning profiles, completely wiped my mac and reinstalled all tools from scratch.
I'm 100% certain that the distribution profile has my device UDID, and matches the certificate.

Crash log:

```
Incident Identifier: 21DCDDC7-FFD0-4217-9309-6653BD667AF7
CrashReporter Key:   1ea92b0cd7119f43fced0aec1e30348e69764939
Hardware Model:      iPhone11,2
Process:             ballz [10603]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/9FFBD7C2-D37A-4788-AD5B-AB465A254EDB/ballz.app/ballz
Identifier:          com.blastproof.dev
Version:             0 (1.3)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.blastproof.dev [2336]


Date/Time:           2020-04-22 10:10:20.0234 +0300
Launch Time:         2020-04-22 10:09:59.8603 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 13.4.1 (17E262)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    2.05.13
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: Namespace SPRINGBOARD, Code 0x8badf00d
Termination Description: SPRINGBOARD, process-launch watchdog transgression: application<com.blastproof.dev>:10603 exhausted real (wall clock) time allowance of 20.00 seconds | ProcessVisibility: Unknown | ProcessState: Running | WatchdogEvent: process-launch | WatchdogVisibility: Foreground | WatchdogCPUStatistics: ( | "Elapsed total CPU time (seconds): 8.660 (user 8.660, system 0.000), 7% CPU", | "Elapsed application CPU time (seconds): 0.144, 0% CPU" | )
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001afe6b7e4 __ulock_wait + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd24cd8 _dlock_wait + 56
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd24c10 _dispatch_once_wait + 124
3   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b006fd18 __CFLookupCoreServicesInternalFunction + 100
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b0054a14 ____CFCoreServicesInternal__FSURLBeginResourcePropertyCacheAccess_block_invoke + 24
5   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2433c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd25a68 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b00517cc __CFURLBeginResourcePropertyCacheAccess + 112
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001aff720e4 -[NSURL setResourceValues:error:] + 96
9   Foundation                      0x00000001b037dcac -[NSFileManager setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:] + 1048
10  Foundation                      0x00000001b038e52c -[NSFileManager createDirectoryAtPath:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:] + 432
11  WebKit                          0x00000001b789ddf4 WebKit::resolveAndCreateReadWriteDirectoryForSandboxExtension+ 1543668 (WTF::String const&) + 112
12  WebKit                          0x00000001b79af62c WebKit::WebProcessPool::platformResolvePathsForSandboxExtensions+ 2663980 () + 220
13  WebKit                          0x00000001b7a00ff8 WebKit::WebProcessPool::resolvePathsForSandboxExtensions+ 2998264 () + 320
14  WebKit                          0x00000001b7a00c8c WebKit::WebProcessPool::WebProcessPool+ 2997388 (API::ProcessPoolConfiguration&) + 1336
15  WebKit                          0x00000001b7727e9c -[WKProcessPool _initWithConfiguration:] + 100
16  WebKit                          0x00000001b7731eb4 -[WKProcessPool init] + 56
17  WebKit                          0x00000001b772b588 -[WKWebViewConfiguration processPool] + 40
18  WebKit                          0x00000001b772b228 -[WKWebViewConfiguration copyWithZone:] + 132
19  WebKit                          0x00000001b7728cdc -[WKWebView _initializeWithConfiguration:] + 136
20  WebKit                          0x00000001b7728c40 -[WKWebView initWithFrame:configuration:] + 80
21  WebKit                          0x00000001b7732388 -[WKWebView initWithFrame:] + 96
22  FairBidSDK                      0x0000000105a4c464 0x105998000 + 738404
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2433c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd25a68 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
25  FairBidSDK                      0x0000000105a4c25c 0x105998000 + 737884
26  FairBidSDK                      0x0000000105a4c1e0 0x105998000 + 737760
27  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001afda1be0 load_images + 952
28  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe8443c invocation function for block in dyld3::AllImages::runInitialzersBottomUp+ 66620 (dyld3::closure::Image const*) + 224
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe76ba8 dyld3::closure::Image::forEachImageToInitBefore(void + 11176 (unsigned int, bool&) block_pointer) const + 104
30  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe84e20 dyld3::AllImages::loadImage+ 69152 (Diagnostics&, unsigned int, dyld3::closure::DlopenClosure const*, bool, bool, bool, bool) + 652
31  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe849ec dyld3::AllImages::dlopen+ 68076 (Diagnostics&, char const*, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool, void const*) + 868
32  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe86434 dyld3::dlopen_internal+ 74804 (char const*, int, void*) + 364
33  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe796c0 dlopen + 116
34  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b008b7e8 _CFBundleDlfcnLoadFramework + 140
35  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001affadee8 _CFBundleLoadExecutableAndReturnError + 432
36  Foundation                      0x00000001b037e7a8 -[NSBundle loadAndReturnError:] + 316
37  ballz                           0x0000000100bb3d54 UnityFrameworkLoad() + 32084 (main.mm:12)
38  ballz                           0x0000000100bb3dfc main + 32252 (main.mm:0)
39  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe751ec start + 4

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001afe6ac10 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd8e808 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 92
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd8e778 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 260
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe8654c dyld3::dlopen_preflight_internal+ 75084 (char const*) + 56
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe79798 dlopen_preflight + 108
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b0082a70 _binaryLoadable + 92
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b0082368 _CFBundleCopyExecutableURLInDirectory2 + 568
7   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b008b21c _CFBundleDlfcnCheckLoaded + 64
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001affac784 _CFBundleEnsureBundleExistsForImagePath + 120
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001affac5f8 CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier + 244
10  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b33ef6a0 0x1b331d000 + 861856
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd8aeb0 __pthread_once_handler + 80
12  libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00000001afd858cc _os_once_callout + 32
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd8ae44 pthread_once + 100
14  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b33ef5f4 0x1b331d000 + 861684
15  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b33f016c _CFNetworkErrorCopyLocalizedDescriptionWithHostname + 84
16  Foundation                      0x00000001b049b7fc localizedDescriptionForError + 68
17  Foundation                      0x00000001b03c7d18 -[NSError+ 576792 (NSURLExtrasInternal) _web_initWithDomain_nowarn:code:URL:] + 172
18  Foundation                      0x00000001b03c2c98 +[NSError+ 556184 (NSURLExtras) _web_errorWithDomain:code:URL:] + 60
19  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b3330284 0x1b331d000 + 78468
20  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd22ec4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
21  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2433c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
22  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2a85c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 568
23  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2b2c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 452
24  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd34928 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 584
25  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd8b714 _pthread_wqthread + 276
26  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd919c8 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 2 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.NSURLSession-work
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001afe6ac10 __psynch_mutexwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd8e808 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_wait + 92
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd8e778 _pthread_mutex_firstfit_lock_slow + 260
3   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe86314 dyld3::dlopen_internal+ 74516 (char const*, int, void*) + 76
4   libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001afe796c0 dlopen + 116
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b006fd50 ____CFLookupCoreServicesInternalFunction_block_invoke + 52
6   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2433c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd25a68 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
8   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b006fd18 __CFLookupCoreServicesInternalFunction + 100
9   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b0054974 ____CFCoreServicesInternal__FSURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey_block_invoke + 24
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2433c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd25a68 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
12  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001b004e65c CFURLCopyResourcePropertyForKey + 284
13  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b334f868 0x1b331d000 + 206952
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2433c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd25a68 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
16  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b334f6fc 0x1b331d000 + 206588
17  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b3532c2c 0x1b331d000 + 2186284
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2433c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
19  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd25a68 _dispatch_once_callout + 32
20  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b3532b24 0x1b331d000 + 2186020
21  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b332eb58 0x1b331d000 + 72536
22  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b3457a88 0x1b331d000 + 1288840
23  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b3321ea8 0x1b331d000 + 20136
24  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b3341b10 0x1b331d000 + 150288
25  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b3321624 0x1b331d000 + 17956
26  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b331ec20 0x1b331d000 + 7200
27  CFNetwork                       0x00000001b3550f3c 0x1b331d000 + 2309948
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd22ec4 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2433c _dispatch_client_callout + 20
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2a85c _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 568
31  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd2b2c4 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 452
32  libdispatch.dylib               0x00000001afd34928 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 584
33  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd8b714 _pthread_wqthread + 276
34  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd919c8 start_wqthread + 8

Thread 3 name:  JavaScriptCore bmalloc scavenger
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001afe6abc0 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd8d1e4 _pthread_cond_wait + 680
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x00000001afebeca8 std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 52392 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 28
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001bf388e88 void std::__1::condition_variable_any::wait<std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex> >+ 577160 (std::__1::unique_lock<bmalloc::Mutex>&) + 104
4   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001bf38cc34 bmalloc::Scavenger::threadRunLoop+ 592948 () + 156
5   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001bf38c958 bmalloc::Scavenger::Scavenger+ 592216 (std::__1::lock_guard<bmalloc::Mutex> const&) + 0
6   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001bf38dbd0 std::__1::__thread_specific_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct>::set_pointer+ 596944 (std::__1::__thread_struct*) + 0
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd898fc _pthread_start + 168
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd919d4 thread_start + 8

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001afd919c0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0xfffffffffffffffc   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000002205   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x00000000000041b7   x5: 0x000000000000000f   x6: 0x0000000000000000   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x0000000000002603   x9: 0x0000000000002204  x10: 0x0000000000000001  x11: 0x0000000000000001
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x00000001ec2cd646  x15: 0x00000001f1dd1f48
   x16: 0x0000000000000203  x17: 0x00000001b006fd1c  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000000
   x20: 0x00000001fda519e8  x21: 0x0000000001000002  x22: 0x0000000000002205  x23: 0x00000002814fd0e0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x00000001ec2cd000  x26: 0x00000001ec2ccfa6  x27: 0x00000001ec2cd000
   x28: 0x0000000000000000   fp: 0x000000016f24d440   lr: 0x00000001afd24cd8
    sp: 0x000000016f24d420   pc: 0x00000001afe6b7e4 cpsr: 0x00000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault

Binary Images:
0x100bac000 - 0x100bb3fff ballz arm64  <d67b6e43f5be3c2a9ff97f5cd243c58b> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9FFBD7C2-D37A-4788-AD5B-AB465A254EDB/ballz.app/ballz
0x100c50000 - 0x100c5bfff libobjc-trampolines.dylib arm64e  <cc80c891368533149cb4d5b6742345d9> /usr/lib/libobjc-trampolines.dylib
0x100e00000 - 0x100e67fff dyld arm64e  <592a4b82e7623dc69409d35dd4a89b6f> /usr/lib/dyld
0x102240000 - 0x104edffff UnityFramework arm64  <f2a707be746e36539d9c5d0cef1be286> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9FFBD7C2-D37A-4788-AD5B-AB465A254EDB/ballz.app/Frameworks/UnityFramework.framework/UnityFramework
0x105998000 - 0x105b43fff FairBidSDK arm64  <b50b1c2e69ad3d4bbdd83ac2ac73431a> /var/containers/Bundle/Application/9FFBD7C2-D37A-4788-AD5B-AB465A254EDB/ballz.app/Frameworks/FairBidSDK.framework/FairBidSDK
0x1afc56000 - 0x1afc6cfff libsystem_trace.dylib arm64e  <426db377a1b83286a6f0b76c54b67296> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib
0x1afc6d000 - 0x1afca0fff libxpc.dylib arm64e  <b18d50ebbc6a3b30ba17d0ec38c1f6cd> /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib
0x1afca1000 - 0x1afca1fff libsystem_blocks.dylib arm64e  <6ff4a25c412e3ce4b1b334944f09ce82> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib
0x1afca2000 - 0x1afd20fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <7f94328bc9753618a7b810f446959ed4> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1afd21000 - 0x1afd5efff libdispatch.dylib arm64e  <783b1b755a873a6eb7235caa2663c75f> /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
0x1afd5f000 - 0x1afd80fff libsystem_malloc.dylib arm64e  <37a79e73afa13935b4ab7f231581c343> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_malloc.dylib
0x1afd81000 - 0x1afd87fff libsystem_platform.dylib arm64e  <5ba431b074c93dfeb5156ba90b508b21> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib
0x1afd88000 - 0x1afd92fff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <40438d42d12a3fa1b5e6a999495181c8> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib
0x1afd93000 - 0x1afdc4fff libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <fbeed962693f3ee780ce9764def56b78> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1afdc5000 - 0x1afe2dfff libcorecrypto.dylib arm64e  <8e3f0607615e3a2faa0acb305aa34025> /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
0x1afe2e000 - 0x1afe43fff libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <7773c226504f342b8879a9dfcbb953f2> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x1afe44000 - 0x1afe73fff libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <08b76adcceb7388fb4b2bdd52c7375e3> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x1afe74000 - 0x1afea8fff libdyld.dylib arm64e  <95b366e7f5bd3308941624b35999029b> /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib
0x1afea9000 - 0x1afeb1fff libsystem_darwin.dylib arm64e  <90a47653df0c346c8cfa1d81ea87b244> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_darwin.dylib
0x1afeb2000 - 0x1aff0ffff libc++.1.dylib arm64e  <cd3dd206dfc53d7a87fa84c638fe62a4> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
0x1aff10000 - 0x1aff51fff libsystem_info.dylib arm64e  <2f8814e1526f3e91800eb99f964e4af6> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib
0x1aff52000 - 0x1b02cffff CoreFoundation arm64e  <9624aafd54373772a5070f357875808d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1b02d0000 - 0x1b033afff SystemConfiguration arm64e  <51f61d30a54a32fe83e0c07fde17d338> /System/Library/Frameworks/SystemConfiguration.framework/SystemConfiguration
0x1b033b000 - 0x1b0606fff Foundation arm64e  <2b7bd2f310a83cba9de35e1f48d9213e> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1b0607000 - 0x1b0639fff libCRFSuite.dylib arm64e  <f96596c0977f3fb98170380eb0f00d36> /usr/lib/libCRFSuite.dylib
0x1b063a000 - 0x1b07bcfff CoreServices arm64e  <596f36898d543a38b2b5bbea04307885> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/CoreServices
0x1b07bd000 - 0x1b081efff libSparse.dylib arm64e  <b3953d5d15143fc2af0f68e3a2f84482> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/libSparse.dylib
0x1b081f000 - 0x1b0d18fff ImageIO arm64e  <fe80d4682d9137ed81277b974db00e16> /System/Library/Frameworks/ImageIO.framework/ImageIO
0x1b0d19000 - 0x1b0d1bfff ConstantClasses arm64e  <25cdea383a8435f68d0ae0ab21f8cf06> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ConstantClasses.framework/ConstantClasses
0x1b0d1c000 - 0x1b0eb5fff CoreText arm64e  <ad12aef7516e3a6b945901e7e920185b> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/CoreText
0x1b0eb6000 - 0x1b0ff3fff Security arm64e  <9586a2f262ad35f18e17c109a5a6912b> /System/Library/Frameworks/Security.framework/Security
0x1b0ff4000 - 0x1b109afff IOKit arm64e  <0673030ac3a53e6684e39a9983b8611b> /System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit
0x1b109b000 - 0x1b10d2fff libMobileGestalt.dylib arm64e  <2c5bcc45e38933258737e4748cd4fc06> /usr/lib/libMobileGestalt.dylib
0x1b10d3000 - 0x1b1131fff libprotobuf.dylib arm64e  <16aa80901ca93d1b850ebb321f5652be> /usr/lib/libprotobuf.dylib
0x1b1132000 - 0x1b1144fff libprotobuf-lite.dylib arm64e  <1ead3579ffd53147a9b0e1448130a5eb> /usr/lib/libprotobuf-lite.dylib
0x1b1145000 - 0x1b13a4fff libicucore.A.dylib arm64e  <2dc1dc2c3d13301aaef393611a29247d> /usr/lib/libicucore.A.dylib
0x1b13cf000 - 0x1b1415fff WirelessDiagnostics arm64e  <4ed0df42185a389f8281246f8d62fe22> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WirelessDiagnostics.framework/WirelessDiagnostics
0x1b1416000 - 0x1b1452fff libAWDSupport.dylib arm64e  <f2ada8e3d47a337ea49581e8cf4243c6> /usr/lib/libAWDSupport.dylib
0x1b1453000 - 0x1b18a2fff CoreAudio arm64e  <9364d152f3343c9bbf44b1a1ced221c2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreAudio.framework/CoreAudio
0x1b18a3000 - 0x1b1b7cfff CoreImage arm64e  <534b276bf3b6335e8a15ed7539c54702> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/CoreImage
0x1b1b7d000 - 0x1b1c70fff LanguageModeling arm64e  <90ce29bed96333cfb02c02a5d1c03678> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/LanguageModeling.framework/LanguageModeling
0x1b1c71000 - 0x1b1cb7fff Lexicon arm64e  <28d1fcd6487b3219a7de87ad3c852558> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Lexicon.framework/Lexicon
0x1b1cb8000 - 0x1b1e3efff libsqlite3.dylib arm64e  <8a0963ecea66378d956bfaaa54508afd> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib
0x1b1e3f000 - 0x1b1e71fff MobileKeyBag arm64e  <c66d0ee2e7943bcdbb2f426de2d3e207> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/MobileKeyBag.framework/MobileKeyBag
0x1b1e72000 - 0x1b1e7bfff libsystem_notify.dylib arm64e  <2509ff7f57e533c994ed85c226baaa67> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib
0x1b1e7c000 - 0x1b2068fff CoreDuet arm64e  <fa494103007535ffaf8db7946a0cbd81> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreDuet.framework/CoreDuet
0x1b2069000 - 0x1b21b0fff Montreal arm64e  <e0c5c3f9e5183e11b8dbae13e50d9427> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Montreal.framework/Montreal
0x1b21b1000 - 0x1b2295fff NLP arm64e  <6cfaf73f401832b9934588016397b4ef> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/NLP.framework/NLP
0x1b2296000 - 0x1b22b4fff CellularPlanManager arm64e  <1f34c041ff2830dd89b843d5f48b5692> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CellularPlanManager.framework/CellularPlanManager
0x1b22b5000 - 0x1b22f2fff AppSupport arm64e  <03e2fc117ef5341d9735507cb71b3538> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AppSupport.framework/AppSupport
0x1b22f3000 - 0x1b27dffff libnetwork.dylib arm64e  <6b86071a0dfc3efda798615ec6a7d591> /usr/lib/libnetwork.dylib
0x1b27e0000 - 0x1b28f1fff ManagedConfiguration arm64e  <f4637fe9b226391198a9f0290ab1eb50> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ManagedConfiguration.framework/ManagedConfiguration
0x1b28f2000 - 0x1b291cfff CoreServicesStore arm64e  <ff17e9858eb83bc6824bb8131c371be7> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreServicesStore.framework/CoreServicesStore
0x1b291d000 - 0x1b293efff UserManagement arm64e  <8b4f8dbce8343e03bcc102929006d637> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UserManagement.framework/UserManagement
0x1b293f000 - 0x1b2bf4fff CoreML arm64e  <5aea650251f73456aed6ba12f4301d8d> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreML.framework/CoreML
0x1b2bf5000 - 0x1b2c0bfff ProtocolBuffer arm64e  <c60dfe3cf75231139412a12e00e8ec05> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/ProtocolBuffer.framework/ProtocolBuffer
0x1b2c0c000 - 0x1b2c26fff CommonUtilities arm64e  <40f314982784388a9cbbfbea228c2e8d> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CommonUtilities.framework/CommonUtilities
0x1b2c27000 - 0x1b2c27fff libenergytrace.dylib arm64e  <f9b52a49c615387e865a6086b7655272> /usr/lib/libenergytrace.dylib
0x1b2c28000 - 0x1b2c5ffff RunningBoardServices arm64e  <a65f835dabc1363288e863203cf93c28> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/RunningBoardServices.framework/RunningBoardServices
0x1b2c60000 - 0x1b2ce0fff BaseBoard arm64e  <3e67a38cf55d3f2886aad33bbe0ed907> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BaseBoard.framework/BaseBoard
0x1b2ce1000 - 0x1b3232fff SiriTTS arm64e  <89c59a7ed45a30b5a81ca87b083cc6e1> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SiriTTS.framework/SiriTTS
0x1b3233000 - 0x1b32a7fff CoreLocation arm64e  <d40048141baf3c69bf1e227b15723610> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreLocation.framework/CoreLocation
0x1b32b5000 - 0x1b330bfff Accounts arm64e  <425be5d5f1da30abb4be823277e41c12> /System/Library/Frameworks/Accounts.framework/Accounts
0x1b330c000 - 0x1b331cfff SharedWebCredentials arm64e  <9443b8cd9eaf3c6597debae0e604ec80> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SharedWebCredentials.framework/SharedWebCredentials
0x1b331d000 - 0x1b367efff CFNetwork arm64e  <1362d01cc0163c49b6176b19826ab3b2> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1b367f000 - 0x1b3760fff UIFoundation arm64e  <af91401f121132409a212132f692b587> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIFoundation.framework/UIFoundation
0x1b3761000 - 0x1b48d4fff UIKitCore arm64e  <66c0bdeb71cf3148af27a5b055fad9a5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1b48d5000 - 0x1b48e3fff AssertionServices arm64e  <1e2c2c8f0b393dcabe859d1b50ca40fa> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssertionServices.framework/AssertionServices
0x1b48e4000 - 0x1b49bdfff CoreTelephony arm64e  <7bb1669074b831ea80db40cd6208e4f8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreTelephony.framework/CoreTelephony
0x1b49be000 - 0x1b49c3fff AggregateDictionary arm64e  <718ba31eaa1b3f4b9a4f98c895135176> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AggregateDictionary.framework/AggregateDictionary
0x1b49c4000 - 0x1b49dafff libsystem_asl.dylib arm64e  <b2e939627b9f37e48c1273e3c5c767a1> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_asl.dylib
0x1b49db000 - 0x1b4a56fff CloudDocs arm64e  <9eab01d404ad3066825cfd683ef75dce> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CloudDocs.framework/CloudDocs
0x1b4a57000 - 0x1b4d8afff CoreData arm64e  <98f0309430ec39d3b10dec7866aefedd> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreData.framework/CoreData
0x1b4d8b000 - 0x1b4fb5fff Vision arm64e  <60855bb208073da0847d8120f16e9de5> /System/Library/Frameworks/Vision.framework/Vision
0x1b4fb6000 - 0x1b4ffafff PhotoFoundation arm64e  <c03e15fef4f13921a241a0c7de746ad5> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoFoundation.framework/PhotoFoundation
0x1b4ffb000 - 0x1b5026fff BoardServices arm64e  <8c3e3899c16130e5969692c38f72ce21> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BoardServices.framework/BoardServices
0x1b5027000 - 0x1b50defff libboringssl.dylib arm64e  <c853ad30336e391fae8a4b573aa66076> /usr/lib/libboringssl.dylib
....
```

Comment: Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a deadlock, but i cannot tell you what is the root cause

your `com.apple.main-thread`

- entered `dyld3::dlopen_internal` (and acquired a lock #1 there)
- entered `__CFLookupCoreServicesInternalFunction` (and stuck trying to acquire a lock #2 there)

...meanwhile...

your `com.apple.NSURLSession-work`

- entered `__CFLookupCoreServicesInternalFunction` (and acquired a lock #2 there)
- entered `dyld3::dlopen_internal` (and stuck trying to acquire a lock #1 there)